# Kentico 9 Email Marketing

Tags: email, kentico

Whenever we send out a marketing email campaign, the emails seem to be sent out roughly every 3 minutes:

[image]

Where would I find the admin setting to increase this frequency to say every 5 seconds?

Comment: Normally, you see the same attempt time for a bunch of emails, how come yours is every 3 minutes for 1 email and then 3 minutes later attempt the next email? If a email is not be sent the task should attempt to send it again.

Also, what hotfix are you on? Check here to see if there are any bug for your version https://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions, not email deliverability questions. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302903/off-topic-my-email-isnt-spam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months of frustration, we discovered that by default, AWS throttles port 25 on EC2 machines. You need to submit [this form](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/) to remove the throttling.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scheduled task in the scheduled task app you can adjust settings on. Also in the Setting under System and Email you can set the batch value.

Before changing any of them I suggest reading the documentation as to what each setting does and what it might affect.

Comment: Thanks. I've already changed both of those, but it's having no effect. The scheduled task was actually set to 1 minute before I changed it, not 3 minutes. Does the change in these settings only affect new campaing sends (i.e. only apply at the point of sending)?

Comment: If you set the scheduled task to process every second, it won't matter because when the task kicks off, it checks already to see if it's running.  If it is, it won't start up another process.  Again, I suggest reading the documentation before making too many changes.

Answer (score 0):

> The emails are sent out using a scheduled task that is executed every 1 minute by default. You can check the status of the scheduled task in the Scheduled tasks application.

https://docs.kentico.com/k9/on-line-marketing-features/email-marketing/troubleshooting-email-campaigns

Additionally there is a seperate task for new emails and queued emails

[image: Mail tasks]

Comment: Thanks Leander (and welcome to Stack Overflow). Changing the frequency of the scheduled task doesn't seem to affect the emails that are already queued to be sent. They still seem to be sent every 3 minutes or so.